# input-group-addon height not working properly when using the label element

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see in the picture the height gets all crazy when I add a label element to the form-group I'm using Bootstrap 3.7

[image]

here is my HTML

```
<div class="form-group date input-group {{ $errors->has('medical_date_test') ? 'has-error' : ''}}">
   <label>Medical date test <span class="required">*</span></label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="medical_date_test" value="{{ old('medical_date_test') }}">
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> </span>
</div>
```

here is a JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/0d2a0kzr/

Comment: better if seen in https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to put a label outside the div class "form-group https://jsfiddle.net/j1aw98jm/2/

```
<label>Medical date test <span class="required">*</span></label>
<div class="form-group date input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="medical_date_test">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks :) sorry it took so long to get back